# Let $x^2 −(m−3)x+m=0,(m\in R)$ be a quadratic equation. Find the value of $m$ for which at least one root is greater than $2$

Tags: inequality, roots, quadratics

> Let $x^2 −(m−3)x+m=0,(m\in R)$ be a quadratic equation. Find the value of $m$ for which at least one root is greater than $2$.

Discriminant$=m^2-10m+9\ge0\implies m\in(-\infty,1]\cup[9,\infty)$

And putting $m=0$, we get both roots less than $2$. Does that mean we can eliminate all the values of $m\le1?$ Why?

Putting $m=9,$ we get double root at $3$. Does that mean all values of $m\ge9$ can be accepted?

Comment: Using Vieta's formulas we get that the sum of roots is equal to $m-3$. If $m\geq 9$ then $m-3\geq 6$ so at least one root will be greater than $2$.

Comment: My answer contained a mistake and I am now trying to fix it. Sorry for any confusion caused.

Comment: @Joe No problem. Thanks.

Comment: @aarbee: I've looked at Siong Thye Goh's solution and I honestly can't think of a better way to solve the inequality. I will re-post my older comment if it is of any use to you.

Comment: @aarbee: We need the larger root to be greater than 2, or the smaller root to be greater than 2. By studying the below table, can you work out why this is equivalent to "the larger root must be greater than 2":\begin{array}{|c|c|c|} \hline & \text{Larger root $>2$} & \text{Larger root $\le2$} \\ \hline \text{Smaller root $>2$} & \text{Possible} & \text{Not possible} \\ \hline \text{Smaller root $\le2$} & \text{Possible} & \text{Possible} \\ \hline \end{array}

Comment: @Joe thankyou so much.

Comment: @aarbee: No worries. I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For the existence of the roots, we need $m\le 1$ or $m \ge 9$.

The roots are

$$\frac{(m-3) \pm \sqrt{(m-3)^2-4m}}{2}$$

We want the larger root to be more than $2$,

$$\frac{m-3+\sqrt{(m-3)^2-4m}}{2}>2$$

$$\sqrt{m^2-10m+9} > 7-m$$

Clearly, any $m \ge 9$ would satisties the inequality as the RHS is negative and LHS is positive.

If $m \le 1$, $$m^2-10m+9 > m^2-14m+49$$

$$m > 10$$

and we find that the intersection is empty.

Summary: $m \ge 9$.

Comment: For $m\ge9$, if we square and solve, $\sqrt{m^2-10m+9} > 7-m$, we get $m\gt10$. Doesn't that mean the intersection is $m\gt10$?

Comment: when $m \le 1$, after squaring both sides we can conclude that $m>10$. but $m \le 1$ and $m>10$ doesn't intersect. On the other hand for $m \ge 9$,  $\sqrt{m^2-10m+9} > 7-m$ clearly holds. Hence we conclude $m \ge 9$.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear earlier. I have edited my comment. Please check.

Comment: Before we square things, note that we have inequality of the form of nonnegative is larger than negative and hence it holds. We can't square it and expect the inequality to be still hold in general, for example $1> -10$, if you square both sides, we can't conclude that $1 > 100$.  Before squaring an inequality, we check if both sides are nonnegative, if so, we can do so and preserve the inequality as the square function is increasing over the nonnegative domain.

Comment: That's a perfect point, thank you so much.

Comment: @aarbee I agree that's a perfect point! I thought the same as you before reading the comment.

Answer (score 1):

We have, two cases.

**Case $1$:** One root is smaller than $2$ and the other is greater than $2$.

$\implies 2$ lies between the roots.

This gives us a condition that: $f(2)<0$

**Case $2$:** Both roots are greater than $2$

This gives us the condition that: $f(2)>0$

Also, $D\ge0$ and $\frac{-b}{2a}>2$

[From graph, Vertex: $(\frac{-b}{2a}, \frac{-D}{4a})$ ]

After solving:

Case $1$ gives $m>10$, and Case $2$ gives $m \in [9,10)$

Taking union of both cases, we get:

$$\boxed{m\in [9, \infty) }$$

Comment: What, no it doesn't, at $m=0$, we get both the roots lesser than $2$.

Comment: If $m=10$, then it is still the case that at least one of the roots is greater than $2$.

Comment: Right you are, thanks, will make a correction.

Comment: No problem. I too made a mistake when I tried to solve this problem. It's harder than it looks!

Answer (score 1):

If $(f(x)=Ax^2+Bx+C=0$ has at least one root $>2$, them
There are two cases: (1) one root $>2$, (2) both roots $>2$
For $f(x)=x^2-(m-3)x+m=0$

Case 1: $B^2\ge 4AC \implies m\le 1~or~ m\ge 9$ and $f(2)<0 \implies m>10$
the overlap of the two conditions gives $n\in(10,\infty)$.

Case2: $B^2>4AC:m\le 1 ~or~ m\ge 9$ and $x_0=-B/(2A) >2 \implies (m-3)/2>2 \implies m>7$ and $f(2)>0 \implies 10-m>0 \implies m<10.$ The overlap of the three intervals is $m \in [9,10)$.

So the union of the two cases gives $m\ge 9.$

Comment: I think you mean $\gt$ sign in two cases in first para?

Comment: OH! yes I corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

The quadratic polynomial $ \ x^2  −  (m−3)x  +  m  \ \ $ represents an "upward-opening" parabola, for which the "vertex form" is $ \ \left(x \  −  \ \frac{ m−3}{2} \right)^2 \ + \ \left( m \ - \ \frac{ [m−3]^2}{4} \right) \ \ . $  It may also be noted that $ \ f(1) \ = \ 4 \ \ , $ independent of the value of $ \ m \ \ . $  So there can be **no zeroes** of the polynomial greater than $ \ 2 \ $ *at the very least* for when the vertex is at $ \ x \le 1 \ \Rightarrow \ \frac{ m−3}{2} \ \le \ 1 \ \Rightarrow \ m \ \le \ 5 \ \ . $

The vertex is tangent to or "below" the $ \ x-$axis for
$$ m \ - \ \frac{ [m−3]^2}{4} \  \le \  0 \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ 0  \ \le  \ -4m \ + \ m^2 \ -6m \ + \ 9 \ \ = \ \ (m - 1)·(m - 9)  $$ $$ \Rightarrow \  \ m \ \le \ 1 \ \ , \ \ m \ \ge \ 9  $$
(as also found by other respondents).  We may thus discard the first inequality.  As for the second, $ \ m \ = \ 9 \ $ gives us the polynomial $ \ \left(x \  −  \ \frac{ 9−3}{2} \right)^2 \ = \ (x \  −  \ 3 )^2 \ \ , $ which has a "double zero" at $ \ x = 3 \ \ $ and is therefore an admissible result.  All larger values of $ \ m \ $ correspond to parabolas with vertices at $ \ x \ \ge \ 3 \ $ and $ \ y \ < \ 0 \ \ , $ so they *always* have an $ \ x-$intercept "to the right" of $ \ x = 3 \ \ . $  Hence, all of the quadratic polynomials $ \ x^2  −  (m−3)x  +  m  \ \ $ have at least one real zero greater than $ \ 2 \ $ for $ \ \mathbf{m \ \ge \ 9} \ \ . $

[In fact, we may note that for $ \ m = 10 \ \ , $ the polynomial becomes $ \ x^2 - 7x + 10 \ = \ (x - 2)·(x - 5) \ \ , $ so *both* zeroes are greater than $ \ 2 \ $ for $ \ 9 \ \le \ m \ < \ 10 \ \ . \ $ ]